MYSQL Using Calculated Field Using Group By or Return Value from previous MAX
Hey stackoverflow community,
I currently do need a hint for a MYSQL query.
In my database are counters are stored for different "tags".
Currently I already get the MIN and MAX from the current month. My challenge is, that I would need the last MAX from the previous month.
Anybody has an idea?
SELECT 
  CONCAT(YEAR(timestamp),"-",LPAD(MONTH(timestamp), 2, '0')) as DATE,
  MIN(counter) as counterMIN,
  MAX(counter) as counterMAX,
  MIN(timestamp) as timestampMIN,
  MAX(timestamp) as timestampMAX,
  tag
FROM `seller` 
WHERE tag LIKE "SYS%"
GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(timestamp),"-",MONTH(timestamp)),`tag`
ORDER BY CONCAT(YEAR(timestamp),"-",LPAD(MONTH(timestamp), 2, '0'))




DATE
tag
counterMIN
counterMAX




2023-12
SYS001
46
312


2024-01
SYS001
476
807



My challenge is that I would need the counterMAX value to be the value from the last month. Therefor I wanted to use a subquery but looks like I cannot do an subquery with an calculated field.



DATE
tag
counterMIN
counterMAX
counterMAXPrevMonth




2023-12
SYS001
46
312
0


2024-01
SYS001
476
807
312



MYSQL Data
CREATE TABLE `seller` (
  `counter` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `seller` (`counter`, `tag`, `timestamp`) VALUES
(46, 'SYS001', '2023-12-10 08:00:00'),
(199, 'SYS001', '2023-12-13 08:00:00'),
(312, 'SYS001', '2023-12-24 08:00:00'),
(476, 'SYS001', '2024-01-08 08:00:00'),
(493, 'SYS001', '2024-01-12 08:00:00'),
(618, 'SYS001', '2024-01-18 08:00:00'),
(807, 'SYS001', '2024-01-28 08:00:00'),
(858, 'SYS001', '2024-02-06 08:00:00'),
(961, 'SYS001', '2024-02-11 08:00:00'),
(1152, 'SYS001', '2024-02-26 08:00:00'),
(1281, 'SYS001', '2024-03-03 08:00:00'),
(1348, 'SYS001', '2024-03-07 08:00:00'),
(1397, 'SYS001', '2024-03-21 08:00:00'),
(1556, 'SYS001', '2024-04-06 07:00:00'),
(1625, 'SYS001', '2024-04-17 07:00:00'),
(172, 'SYS002', '2023-12-10 08:00:00'),
(334, 'SYS002', '2023-12-21 08:00:00'),
(519, 'SYS002', '2023-12-27 08:00:00'),
(630, 'SYS002', '2024-01-14 08:00:00'),
(790, 'SYS002', '2024-01-17 08:00:00'),
(884, 'SYS002', '2024-01-30 08:00:00'),
(928, 'SYS002', '2024-02-12 08:00:00'),
(938, 'SYS002', '2024-02-15 08:00:00'),
(1103, 'SYS002', '2024-02-23 08:00:00'),
(1289, 'SYS002', '2024-02-25 08:00:00'),
(1361, 'SYS002', '2024-02-27 08:00:00'),
(1553, 'SYS002', '2024-03-07 08:00:00'),
(1597, 'SYS002', '2024-03-15 08:00:00'),
(1604, 'SYS002', '2024-03-22 08:00:00'),
(1762, 'SYS002', '2024-03-29 08:00:00');

Hint for the query to resolve also MAX value from the previous month

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m') as `DATE`,
         MIN(counter) as counterMIN,
         MAX(counter) as counterMAX,
         MIN(`timestamp`) as timestampMIN,
         MAX(`timestamp`) as timestampMAX,
         tag
  FROM `seller` 
  WHERE tag LIKE "SYS%"
  GROUP BY `DATE`,`tag`
--  ORDER BY `DATE`
)
SELECT *, LAG(counterMAX) OVER (PARTITION BY tag ORDER BY `DATE`) counterMAXPrevMonth
FROM cte
ORDER BY tag, `DATE`




DATE
counterMIN
counterMAX
timestampMIN
timestampMAX
tag
counterMAXPrevMonth




2023-12
46
312
2023-12-10 08:00:00
2023-12-24 08:00:00
SYS001
null


2024-01
476
807
2024-01-08 08:00:00
2024-01-28 08:00:00
SYS001
312


2024-02
858
1152
2024-02-06 08:00:00
2024-02-26 08:00:00
SYS001
807


2024-03
1281
1397
2024-03-03 08:00:00
2024-03-21 08:00:00
SYS001
1152


2024-04
1556
1625
2024-04-06 07:00:00
2024-04-17 07:00:00
SYS001
1397


2023-12
172
519
2023-12-10 08:00:00
2023-12-27 08:00:00
SYS002
null


2024-01
630
884
2024-01-14 08:00:00
2024-01-30 08:00:00
SYS002
519


2024-02
928
1361
2024-02-12 08:00:00
2024-02-27 08:00:00
SYS002
884


2024-03
1553
1762
2024-03-07 08:00:00
2024-03-29 08:00:00
SYS002
1361



fiddle
